# Is it possible to use a 4G LTE Huawei mobile gateway Router to connect NBN internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mobile-broadband

**Is it possible to use HUAWEI E5186s-61a 4G LTE Mobile Gateway Router to replace NBN wireless router?**

At home I have [Superloop NBN](https://www.superloop.com/consumer/home-broadband/nbn.html)(Australia) NBN connection.

My understanding is the NBN Internet requires NBN Wireless Router, but I have the Huawei Mobile Router. Can I use it to connect to my NBN Internet?

I have tried and I was expecting nothing working.

> *Surprisingly, 1 of 3 connected devices works~!!!!*

The other 2 don't. After checking IP address, I found that the working one has IP: 0.0.0.0

So how to make the router working for all connected devices?

Here is my NBN Box attached to the wall:
[image]

Here is my Huawei 4G LTE Mobile Wireless Gateway Router
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm if your connection is coming in as an Ethernet cable? Looking at a pic of the back of one of these routers online I speculate you may be able to plug the ISP connection into port. 4 (labeled man/wan), the other devices into the other van ports, then go into the router settings and change port4 to act as a WAN port?

Comment: hi @davidgo has it to be port 4? or the ISP connection could be connect to any port?  what does it mean labled man/wan? my other devices are mobiles and I would like to use the Huawei mobile router as a normal NBN wireless router. Is it possible?  what is the minimal cost I need to spend if it's possible but need to purchase anything? thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I can't answer definitively - but it is implied that the ISP side does need to be port 4. Port 4 on the pic I saw is labelled LAN/WAN - and WAN means ISP side in this context. Generally the hardware in these types of devices allow the ports to be assigned differently, but require appropriate software configuration.

Comment: LAN =  local (area) network, WAN stands for Wide Area Network and means ISP connection. I expect that you are also confusing 4g with WIFI. I'd be stunned if those routers can use the cellular network protocol. They likely use WIFI, which is also standard on smartphones. You can generally use WiFi and lan connections together without special setup (other then WiFi name and password) Note I'm slightly simplifying everything I am saying - its practically correct in most simple setup cases though.

Comment: Of you need to purchase something it likely does not need to be expensive, but we would need to know how you connect to the ISP. I'm 99.9% certain NBN is delivered differently depending on your location/building (Aussies have been scammed - I KNOW its not always a fibre connection). Can you upload a picture of any telco provided box or connection on your wall?

Comment: hi @davidgo thanks a lot for your explanation. I have uploaded my NBN Box and the Huawei Mobile Router. please have a look. Hopefully, we could make it work without spending anything. I use Superloop, the link to its website is in my question as well.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding the question. What exactly is your goal? Is it to (basically) replace the ISP? If that’s the case, can you place the 4G router where the optical router is? // Or is the goal to simply have Wi-Fi?

Comment: @DanielB I'm pretty sure the goal is to use the 4g (Cellulr) router as an Ethernet router and have it provide Internet over WIFI.

Comment: Without access to the router I can't help further to get this working g if its even possible. The manual I could basically amounts to saying "speak to your provider".  As you have fibre to the home presented as an ethernet cable you should be able to get away with a cheap Ethernet/WiFi router. Are you on a tight budget? (If so I can try find you a cheap router, as the $80 the mega-retailers want obsurd money for entry level, although you do somewhat get what you pay for) The sad thing is I have thrown away suitable routers because they have so little value in NZ!

Comment: hi @DanielB thanks for your comment, yes as davidgo said, I would like to use the 4G Mobile router as an Ethernet router and have it provide Internet over WIFI.

Comment: thanks @davidgo my thought is the 4G Mobile router also has WIFI function and 1 device can connect to Internet wirelessly, so probably I could do something to re-purpose the 4G Mobile router to make it behave like an Ethernet router?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I suspect what is happening is the router is acting like an access point - converting Ethernet to WiFi.  It is not, however, acting as a router - specifically it is not sharing the connection or providing the kind of firewall+IP address allocation you need. In order to repurposed the router you need to make the 4th port into a WAN port. I am unclear if your software supports this (its likely curated by the telco that supplied it), and if so, how to turn it on. The hardware should be capable of doing this, but that may not help you.